# iOS App Arabic Localization Issue

Tags: ios, iphone, localization, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I am working on an application, where I have to implement arbic as well as english locale.
I have made seperate storyboards for both languages. Problem is autolayout constraints are automatically flipping my views. Is there anyway to stop auto flipping for arabic locale?

I want to design views myself for arabic.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Constraints by default respect language direction, but you can turn this off by selecting the constraint, and then in the Attributes Inspector, unchecking the `Respect language direction` in the `First Item` and the `Second Item` pop down menus.

Note that that option isn't available for all constraints.